# What shall I do if I want use new feature without update compiler?

Tags: c++

eg. I want to use `std::byte` only, I don't need other new features in 17. but maybe use in future. So what shall I do now?

1

```
#if __cplusplus  < 201703L
namespace std {
  enum class byte : unsigned char {};
}
#endif
```

2

```
#if __cplusplus  < 201703L
namespace std {
  typedef byte uint8_t;
}
#endif
```

or without adding these in `std` namespace, just use `uint8_t`.

or any other suggestion...

I understand 1 & 2 is very ugly, but the simplest to me.

Comment: Do you not at least have C++11 so that '2' can be a using statement instead. In either scenario, I'm rarely a fan of mucking around in `std::`. If you want to use the custom type, I'd say go ahead but don't bother putting it in `std::`.

Comment: As far as I know: if you are adding anything to `std` namespace: you are invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius [Extending the namespace std](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std). There's a few things you can add to the namespace, but it's all related to templates of types that are already declared there.

Comment: @sweenish @AlgirdasPreidžius thanks, I thought even it's UB because `byte` symbol is complete not exist in 11, might be fine...never break the rule is the best choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want your code to be backward-compatible with older C++ versions, you typically provide your own implementations of the missing component in your compatibility layer. For example, you create a `byte.h` header that defines `byte` type in your own namespace, something like this:

```
#include <cstddef>

namespace my_namespace {

#if __cplusplus  < 201703L
enum class byte : unsigned char {};
#else
using std::byte;
#endif

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::byte` is not completely implementable in pure C++. You need some compiler support to be able to copy an object to a `std::byte[N]` and read from it without UB.

If your only using it for the bitwise-operators, you could do an implementation like this:

```cpp
enum class byte : unsigned char {};

template <class IntegerType>
constexpr IntegerType to_integer(byte b) noexcept { return static_cast<IntegerType>(b); }

template <class IntegerType>
constexpr byte operator <<(byte b, IntegerType shift) noexcept { return byte(static_cast<unsigned int>(b) << shift); }
template <class IntegerType>
constexpr byte operator >>(byte b, IntegerType shift) noexcept { return byte(static_cast<unsigned int>(b) >> shift); }
constexpr byte operator|(byte l, byte r) noexcept { return byte(static_cast<unsigned int>(l) | static_cast<unsigned int>(r)); }
constexpr byte operator&(byte l, byte r) noexcept { return byte(static_cast<unsigned int>(l) & static_cast<unsigned int>(r)); }
constexpr byte operator^(byte l, byte r) noexcept { return byte(static_cast<unsigned int>(l) ^ static_cast<unsigned int>(r)); }
constexpr byte operator~(byte b) noexcept { return byte(~static_cast<unsigned int>(b)); }

template <class IntegerType>
constexpr byte& operator<<=(byte& b, IntegerType shift) noexcept { return b = b << shift; }
template <class IntegerType>
constexpr byte& operator>>=(byte& b, IntegerType shift) noexcept { return b = b >> shift; }
constexpr byte& operator|=(byte& l, byte r) noexcept { return l = l | r; }
constexpr byte& operator&=(byte& l, byte r) noexcept { return l = l & r; }
constexpr byte& operator^=(byte& l, byte r) noexcept { return l = l ^ r; }
```

Which omits the checking if `IntegerType` is actually an integer (and the object representation support as noted earlier), but is otherwise feature complete.

You probably want to only use this and not `std::byte` at all, because you may run into conflicts where some files were compiled with `std::byte` and others with the replacement, leading to weird linker errors.